# Full screen in VirtualBox without a desktop environment

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, xorg, fullscreen, minimal-install

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on VirtualBox 6.1.16, my host is Windows 10 Insider Preview.

I'm trying to get full screen *without* a desktop environment. I want to run a minimalist build with `dwm` as my window manager and `st` as my terminal emulator.

I tried installing the `virtualbox-guest-x11` package. It automatically installs a bunch of recommended packages, including a basic Gnome environment. After reboot, it presents me the GDM login screen. If I login to another tty, install and run `startx`, the X server can't go full screen, while the Gnome X server (which I don't want) can. I can run dwm and st in the X server I started with startx, but it won't go full screen like the Gnome one.

I tried following the VirtualBox documentation and install the guest additions mounting the CD and running `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`. The result is the same.

These screenshots are from the same VM:
[image]
tty1 with the Gnome environment installed automatically by `virtualbox-guest-x11`.
[image]
tty2 when I do a `startx` with `dwm` and `st` installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use scaled view

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I'm looking for, using Scaled View distorts the proportions of windows and fonts, when I go full screen it just expands the pixels and makes them big. I want VirtualBox to scale the resolution according to the size of the virtual machine in my host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

Both the VirtualBox Guest Additions and Xorg were installed correctly, hence my confusion. However, this was not enough to get a working full screen. VirtualBox Guest Additions installs a program called `VBoxClient`, typically located at `/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-<version number>/bin`. If you run that program with the argument `--vmsvga`, you get full screen. Perhaps GNOME automatically searches for this program and runs it if it's installed, but since I wanted a minimal install without any desktop environment, I had to do it manually. You can also run `VBoxClient` with the arguments `--clipboard` and `--draganddropg`, for shared clipboard and drag and drop functionality, it only accepts one argument per call, though. Alternatively, you can run `VBoxClient-all`, it's the same command, but it enables everything at once.

It needs to run after the X server is started, so I prepended a single line, `VBoxClient-all &`, in my `~/.xinitrc` file, and now I have full screen whenever I start X.